# Outputting jQuery in PHP, quotes issue

Tags: php, jquery, quote

I have this i'm trying to output in PHP:

```
$this->Js->buffer("
    var searchTerm = $(this).html();
    var searchId = $(this).attr('data-tag');
    $('.tags').append('<input type='text' value='+searchTerm+' name='data[Tag][tags]['+searchId+']'');
");
```

But i'm unsure about quotes and javascript variables as well.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also stop single and double quotes from tripping you up by swapping singles for doubles, e.g.:

```
$this->Js->buffer("
    var searchTerm = $(this).html();
    var searchId = $(this).attr('data-tag');
    $('.tags').append('<input type=\"text\" value='+searchTerm+' name=\"data[Tag][tags]['+searchId+']\">');
");
```

Would output:

```
var searchTerm = $(this).html();
var searchId = $(this).attr('data-tag');
$('.tags').append('<input type="text" value='+searchTerm+' name="data[Tag][tags]['+searchId+']">');
```

Comment: Ugh, escape orgies are bad. If you have to escape something in a string that is longer than a few characters or have to escape quite many quotes, you are likely to be doing something bad. Your answer is perfectly fine from a technical point of view but it's still bad code.

Comment: There should probably be a `>` at the end

Comment: Yep, true enough, Znarkus. I just used the string as given, without too much inspection of its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `'` delimiter inside of your strings.

Answer (score 1):

Escape ' using \'  and " using \" characters while outputting

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$this->Js->buffer("
    var searchTerm = $(this).html();
    var searchId = $(this).attr('data-tag');
    $('.tags').append('<input type='text' value='\"+searchTerm+\"' name='data[Tag][tags]['\"+searchId+\"']');
");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Js->buffer("
    var searchTerm = $(this).html();
    var searchId = $(this).attr('data-tag');
    $('.tags').append('<input type='text' value='+searchTerm+' name='data[Tag][tags]['+searchId+']'');
");
```

That is your code. Inside the PHP `""` you must write single quotes `'` or escape double quotes `\"`. You have chosen to use single quotes, which is fine, except the generated JS code must also follow these rules.

```
$('.tags').append('<input type='text' value='+searchTerm+' name='data[Tag][tags]['+searchId+']'');
```

The problem here is `'<input type='text'...>`. First, you missed the `>` ;-) Second, you must either use `"` or `\'` to wrap `text`. `'<input type="text"...>'` is okay. But this would conflict with PHP, since `"` was used for the PHP string. Therefor you'd have to escape the double qoutes: `'<input type=\"text\"...>'`.

**But seriously**, this is a mess. Try to write Javascript directly in the HTML template, it will save you so much head ache.

Comment: The full last JS line should look like this, properly escaped: `$('.tags').append('<input type=\"text\" value=\"'+searchTerm+'\" name=\"data[Tag][tags]['+searchId+']\">');`

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY need to put JS in your PHP files (it's bad, save it in an external file and then include it), use the [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax (or [`nowdoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)):

```
$this->JS->buffer(<<<EOF
    var searchTerm = $(this).html();
    var searchId = $(this).data('tag');
    $('.tags').append('<input type="text" value="'+searchTerm+'" name="data[Tag][tags][' +searchId+']"');
EOF
);
```

Comment: It's using CakePHP's JS buffer

Comment: Then I'd say CakePHP is bad (actually, I already did so before :p). But you could easily load a file: `$this->JS->buffer(file_get_contents('path/to/your/file.js'));`